# Am I right about subsets of $ f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} $?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's say we have a function declared like that: $ f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} $

$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$

$a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$

$a \neq 0$

Now there are 3 sets. Set $A$ contains all possible variations of $f$. Below are two extra sets:

$B=\{f \in A | f(0)\in\mathbb{Q}\}$

$C=\{f \in A | f[\mathbb{Q}]⊆\mathbb{Q}\}$

As far as I understand, set $B$ contains an infinite amount of $f$ functions where $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}/\{0\} ,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c \in \mathbb{Q}$ .

I can also say that set $C$ contains an infinite amount of $f$ functions where $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$ .

Do I understand the sets $B,C$ right? Thanks.

Comment: What is a variation of $f$?

Comment: I think that it is unknown

Comment: My interpretation is that $A=\{f(x)=ax^2+bx+c\mid a,b,c\in\Bbb R,a\neq0\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct, although I would replace "contains an infinite amount of $f$ functions" with "contains exactly the functions $f$". Otherwise, the sets $B$ and $C$ could contain other elements that do not match your description!

It feels a bit weird to just answer with yes/no, so I'll detail the reasonings for $B$ and $C$. In both cases, it is clear that functions that satisfy your descriptions are included in the respective sets.

Reciprocally, if $f\in B$, then $f(0)=c\in\Bbb Q$. In addition, by definition of $f$, $a\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ and $b\in\Bbb R$. So
$$B=\{f(x)=ax^2+bx+c\mid a\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\},b\in\Bbb R,c\in\Bbb Q\}.$$

And if $f\in C$, then $f(0)=c\in\Bbb Q$. Considering $x=1$ and $x=-1$, we find that $f(1)-c=a+b\in\Bbb Q$ and $f(-1)-c=a-b\in\Bbb Q$, so $a=\frac12(a+b+a-b)\in\Bbb Q$ and $b=\frac12(a+b-(a-b))\in\Bbb Q$. So
$$C=\{f(x)=ax^2+bx+c\mid a,b,c\in\Bbb Q,a\neq0\}.$$

Comment: You forgot to mention $a\neq 0$ in the last line.

Comment: You are correct! I added it.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that set $A$ contains all **possibilities** of $f,$ then the set $B$ is infinite because it contains all $ax^2+bc+c$ such that $c \in \mathbb{Q},$ so $$\mathrm{card}\, B \geq \mathrm{card}\, \Bbb Q.$$

Moreover, set $\{ax^2+bx+c:a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}, a\neq0\}\subseteq C$ and so again $C$ has to be infinite.