# Cardinality of an infinite set of functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, cardinals

There is a set A:

```
A = {a,b,c belongs to R | f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c, x belongs to R, a is not 0}
```

And set C is:

```
C = {f belongs to A | f[Q] contained in Q}
```

Is the set C from cardinality aleph or aleph nor?

This is what I came up with:

### C is aleph:

1. f[Q] belongs to P(Q), thus C is aleph, as there are P(Q) different functions in this group
2. for h:P(Q) --> C, h(x) = f: R--> R, f[Q] = x, f(x) if x not belongs to Q, x. h is one to one thus has the same cardinality as P(Q)

### C is aleph nor:

1. Both a, b, c must be from Q thus C is Q * Q * Q thus aleph nor
2. There can be functions in A where rationals will produce non rational, and specific sets of rationals are cannot be created using any type of function in A, such as Q itself.

I believe it to be aleph, but did not manage to find any proof to that. which cardinality does this set belongs to? And what is the proof for that?

Comment: Learning MathJax would make your question clearer.  What's aleph nor?  Do you mean $\aleph_0$?  What's the difference between aleph and aleph nor?  Does one mean the cardinality of $\Bbb{R}$?  That's not $\aleph_0$ and we don't know which $\aleph$ it is.

Comment: You can see some hint here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3654824/am-i-right-about-subsets-of-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr

Comment: @badjohn cardinality of R is aleph and cardinality of N is aleph nor

Comment: That's not the usual usage.

Comment: @Dave93 this is the exact question! except there he is not asking about cardinality....

Comment: It should be ℵ0

Comment: For the cardinality of $\Bbb{R}$, $\mathfrak{c}$ is sometimes used or $\beth_1$ or $2^{\aleph_0}$ but I have never seen just $\aleph$.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9475/symbol-for-the-cardinality-of-the-continuum.

Comment: @badjohn This is how it is used in my university...

Comment: Very strange.  Which university?  Is the class taught in English?  I have seen some confusion before when other languages were involved.

Comment: I guess that by "aleph nor", you mean $\aleph_0$.  This gets spoken in a variety of ways e.g. zero, null, and naught but nor seems very unlikely.  Maybe you are thinking of naught.  See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number.

Comment: @badjohn The class is taught in hebrew, so the letters of the cardinality is from the same languge. this is probaly the resone.

Comment: Usage in Hebrew appears to be different to English.  Unqualified $\aleph$ is rare in English.  Care is needed, see the Continuum Hypothesis for why.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis

Comment: My apologies for English stealing your letters and using them differently.  It happens to us as well.  Many languages borrow English words but don't use them as we do.

Comment: @badjohn I am glad that א is used as it is quite rare to see Hebrew alphabet used in mathematics (at least as far as I know)

Comment: @badjohn: You can find numerous comments I left on the site saying that this notation is due to Hausdorff and while not very common today, it is still used in some courses, especially those geared towards non-mathematicians (but also in introductory courses to set theory for mathematicians sometimes), at least in Israel.

Comment: Aviv, "$\aleph_0$" would be aleph *nought* (or naught), or aleph *null*. There's no "aleph nor".

Comment: Your notation is very unclear. Do you mean $C$ is the set of quadratics with real coefficients that map rationals to rationals?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, I spotted the Hebrew usage.  In fact, one of my references above is a previous question with an answer by you.  Nonetheless, is it reasonable to say that the usage is potentially confusing in English?

Comment: @avivgood2 It will be useful to learn to usage MathJax to format your questions.  This can be used to enter many mathematical symbols such as $\pi$ and the rest of the Greek alphabet.  It also supports $\aleph$ and $\beth$ as they are commonly used for infinite cardinalities.  I have not seen any other Hebrew letters used and I don't know whether MathJax supports them.  Let's try: $\gimel$, $\daleth$.  So, they worked.  What's the next letter?  I'm sorry, I have reached the limits of my knowledge of Hebrew.

Comment: @badjohn Well, after a little bit of reading about the mathjax syntax I think the following will work: $/hey$ or $ה$ or $/hay$ or $ה$, $hey$, $hay$? $hebrew_hay$  Edit: it did not

Comment: Well, MathJax is for writing maths not Hebrew.  Aleph and Beth are used in maths.  I was surprised that Gimel and Daleth worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since$$c=f(0),\,a+b=f(1)-f(0),\,3a+b=f(2)-f(1)$$implies$$a=\frac{f(0)+f(2)}{2}-f(1),\,b=\frac{f(0)-f(2)}{2}+f(1),$$specifying the coefficients of $f\in C$ is equivalent to specifying arbitrary rational values of $f(0),\,f(1),\,f(2)$. So $|C|=|\Bbb Q|^3=|\Bbb N|$, which English-speaking mathematicians usually denote $\aleph_0$ so that $|R|=2^{\aleph_0}$.